# How to change font-family and text of a "lottie" json file?

Tags: json, animation

I want to use a [lottie json file](https://lottiefiles.com/animations/text-animate-pxbEX8NOYh) in my WordPress website. But I need to change the font-family and actual text of it. Here is the json file of that lottie:

```
{"v":"5.6.3","fr":30,"ip":0,"op":126,"w":1920,"h":1080,"nm":"healthwire","ddd":0,"assets":[],"fonts":{"list":[{"fName":"KlinicSlab-MediumItalic","fFamily":"Klinic Slab","fStyle":"Medium Italic","ascent":71.7056274414063}]},"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":5,"nm":"Healthwire","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[321.377,623.077,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"hasMask":true,"masksProperties":[{"inv":false,"mode":"n","pt":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[5.75,-20.625],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[24,26],[5,-24],[-45,-10],[0,0],[0,0],[-7.5,11.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[40,-32.5],[-23,-23.5],[-0.5,38],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-5.5,4],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-21.5,7],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[4.499,-60.5],[0,0],[-2,2],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-19,12],[-9,-14.5],[7.5,-47],[-12.001,2.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[2,8.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-0.5,-1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[26,-14],[0,0],[0,0],[-15,1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-14,11.5],[-0.001,31.073],[0,0],[4.616,6.107],[12.522,-6.81],[-0.5,1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,-1.5],[0,0],[-16,10],[-5.5,-7],[0,0],[0.5,-1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-5.75,20.625],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-24,-26],[-5,24],[45,10],[0,0],[0,0],[7.5,-11.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-40,32.5],[23,23.5],[0.5,-38],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[5.5,-4],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[21.5,-7],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-4.5,60.5],[0,0],[2,-2],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[19,-12],[9,14.5],[-7.5,47],[11.999,-2.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-2,-8.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0.5,1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-26,14],[0,0],[0,0],[15,-1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[12.242,-10.056],[0,-4.462],[0,0],[-4.616,-6.107],[-15.5,15],[0.5,-1],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,1.5],[0,0],[16,-10],[5.5,7],[0,0],[-0.5,1.5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[37.873,-179.077],[73.998,-179.327],[109.498,-179.952],[70.998,-165.827],[61.248,-118.952],[54.998,-83.577],[51.123,-52.077],[45.623,-26.077],[9.123,-8.077],[42.123,-9.077],[78.623,-6.577],[48.123,-17.077],[45.623,-77.577],[72.623,-94.077],[142.623,-94.077],[187.124,-98.077],[196.123,-178.077],[169.624,-179.077],[232.124,-181.577],[201.123,-169.577],[197.623,-118.077],[178.623,-61.577],[172.123,-20.077],[141.623,-8.077],[203.623,-6.577],[213.624,-58.077],[254.623,-61.077],[309.624,-71.077],[332.623,-119.077],[251.624,-82.077],[286.623,-7.077],[334.623,-18.077],[355.123,-71.077],[368.623,-118.577],[395.623,-148.577],[466.624,-145.577],[498.123,-145.077],[492.623,-108.077],[488.123,-89.577],[418.124,-122.077],[398.123,-19.577],[482.124,-57.577],[502.623,-121.577],[492.623,-71.077],[484.624,-31.077],[488.123,-5.077],[508.624,-6.577],[536.623,-189.077],[533.123,-211.577],[553.623,-207.577],[583.623,-208.077],[563.124,-103.577],[554.623,-30.077],[580.624,-6.577],[604.123,-95.577],[610.624,-154.577],[635.124,-185.077],[656.624,-186.077],[656.624,-161.077],[652.624,-123.077],[625.123,-123.077],[696.623,-123.077],[639.624,-82.077],[648.124,-8.077],[680.623,-8.077],[720.624,-151.077],[708.124,-195.577],[707.123,-221.077],[732.124,-210.077],[758.124,-206.577],[754.623,-170.577],[743.123,-110.077],[732.124,-51.577],[726.124,-10.577],[755.124,-104.077],[813.124,-124.077],[825.123,-73.577],[828.624,-7.577],[855.623,-11.577],[869.624,-79.077],[854.124,-121.077],[872.124,-122.077],[895.624,-122.077],[918.123,-11.577],[972.624,-82.577],[968.124,-127.077],[954.623,-126.077],[977.623,-111.077],[984.123,-78.077],[992.124,-36.577],[999.623,-8.577],[1038.624,-55.577],[1055.624,-107.077],[1036.124,-126.077],[1000.624,-107.577],[1001.124,-138.077],[1031.624,-155.077],[1078.124,-158.077],[1079.124,-124.077],[1122.124,-123.077],[1112.624,-62.077],[1109.124,-34.577],[1110.624,-14.077],[1135.124,-7.077],[1148.139,-172.577],[1148.124,-179.577],[1140.739,-193.97],[1115.624,-193.077],[1123.124,-162.577],[1141.124,-165.577],[1146.624,-172.077],[1146.624,-191.577],[1166.124,-128.077],[1177.124,-120.577],[1207.124,-122.077],[1204.124,-98.577],[1196.124,-66.577],[1193.124,-42.077],[1183.124,-3.077],[1216.624,-102.577],[1257.624,-126.077],[1272.624,-117.577],[1272.624,-100.077],[1283.624,-63.077],[1308.124,-59.577],[1363.124,-70.077],[1397.124,-100.077],[1364.124,-131.077],[1319.624,-100.077],[1308.624,-44.577],[1320.124,-16.077],[1356.624,-7.577],[1386.124,-13.077],[1397.124,-19.077]],"c":false},"ix":1},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":3},"x":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"nm":"Mask 1"}],"ef":[{"ty":22,"nm":"Stroke","np":13,"mn":"ADBE Stroke","ix":1,"en":1,"ef":[{"ty":10,"nm":"Path","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0001","ix":1,"v":{"a":0,"k":1,"ix":1}},{"ty":7,"nm":"All Masks","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0010","ix":2,"v":{"a":0,"k":1,"ix":2}},{"ty":7,"nm":"Stroke Sequentially","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0011","ix":3,"v":{"a":0,"k":1,"ix":3}},{"ty":2,"nm":"Color","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0002","ix":4,"v":{"a":0,"k":[0.913725495338,0,0,1],"ix":4}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Brush Size","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0003","ix":5,"v":{"a":0,"k":51.8,"ix":5}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Brush Hardness","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0004","ix":6,"v":{"a":0,"k":0.95,"ix":6}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Opacity","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0005","ix":7,"v":{"a":0,"k":1,"ix":7}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Start","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0008","ix":8,"v":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":8}},{"ty":0,"nm":"End","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0009","ix":9,"v":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"t":0,"s":[0]},{"t":121,"s":[100]}],"ix":9}},{"ty":7,"nm":"Spacing","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0006","ix":10,"v":{"a":0,"k":15,"ix":10}},{"ty":7,"nm":"Paint Style","mn":"ADBE Stroke-0007","ix":11,"v":{"a":0,"k":3,"ix":11}}]}],"t":{"d":{"k":[{"s":{"s":311,"f":"KlinicSlab-MediumItalic","t":"Healthwire","j":0,"tr":0,"lh":373.2,"ls":0,"fc":[0.165,0.765,0.969]},"t":0}]},"p":{},"m":{"g":1,"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2}},"a":[]},"ip":0,"op":900,"st":0,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"Shape Layer 1","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[960,540,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.866666666667,0,0,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":2,"ix":5},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0,0,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"bm":0,"nm":"Fill 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":900,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[],"chars":[{"ch":"H","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":75.5,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-0.604,0],[26.285,0],[27.594,-7.15],[18.53,-7.15],[22.055,-27.09],[54.584,-27.09],[51.059,-7.15],[41.995,-7.15],[40.686,0],[67.676,0],[68.884,-7.15],[59.921,-7.15],[68.179,-54.181],[77.243,-54.181],[78.452,-61.331],[51.462,-61.331],[50.253,-54.181],[59.317,-54.181],[55.893,-34.543],[23.364,-34.543],[26.788,-54.181],[35.852,-54.181],[37.061,-61.331],[10.172,-61.331],[8.862,-54.181],[17.926,-54.181],[9.567,-7.15],[0.604,-7.15]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"H","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"H","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"e","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":42.7,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-11.179,0],[-3.424,1.813],[0,0],[5.035,0],[0.504,7.956],[0,11.682],[8.661,0],[0,-15.005]],"o":[[5.338,0],[0,0],[-4.129,1.913],[-7.251,0],[14.2,-0.705],[0,-6.445],[-13.495,0],[0,13.193]],"v":[[21.954,1.108],[35.55,-2.115],[36.96,-9.265],[23.062,-5.64],[10.977,-17.02],[39.88,-33.234],[26.688,-44.211],[2.417,-18.228]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"e","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ind":1,"ty":"sh","ix":2,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[10.172,-0.403],[-7.15,0],[0,-2.518]],"o":[[1.813,-8.359],[4.23,0],[0,6.647]],"v":[[11.38,-23.465],[26.285,-37.766],[31.924,-33.032]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"e","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"e","np":5,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"a","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":54.2,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-9.366,0],[-3.726,4.633],[-5.942,0],[-1.913,0.604],[0,0],[1.813,0],[-0.604,3.122],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[6.647,0],[0,-15.308]],"o":[[6.345,0],[0.201,4.733],[2.417,0],[0,0],[-1.41,0.504],[-2.921,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-2.417,-4.834],[-12.085,0],[0,12.79]],"v":[[19.135,1.108],[34.543,-6.647],[43.304,1.007],[50.153,-0.101],[51.361,-6.747],[46.124,-5.64],[42.801,-10.272],[48.541,-43.103],[39.981,-43.103],[38.672,-36.053],[25.076,-44.211],[2.518,-18.53]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"a","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ind":1,"ty":"sh","ix":2,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[8.762,0],[0,8.258],[-8.661,0],[0,-7.855]],"o":[[-6.445,0],[0,-10.574],[6.747,0],[0,10.172]],"v":[[21.854,-5.539],[11.38,-18.631],[26.587,-37.564],[37.061,-24.573]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"a","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"a","np":5,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"l","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":24,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-8.258,0],[-1.913,0.604],[0,0],[1.813,0],[-0.504,3.223],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[2.518,0],[0,0],[-1.41,0.504],[-2.82,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-1.007,6.345]],"v":[[12.488,1.007],[19.437,-0.101],[20.544,-6.747],[15.308,-5.64],[11.984,-10.272],[22.76,-71.201],[6.546,-71.201],[5.237,-64.352],[12.891,-64.352],[3.424,-10.776]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"l","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"l","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"t","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":32.3,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-7.553,0],[-2.518,1.208],[0,0],[3.726,0],[-0.705,4.23],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[4.129,0],[0,0],[-2.014,0.705],[-3.827,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-1.611,8.762]],"v":[[16.718,1.108],[27.09,-1.208],[28.299,-7.755],[19.537,-5.64],[14.401,-11.481],[18.732,-36.255],[31.119,-36.255],[32.428,-43.103],[19.839,-43.103],[21.854,-54.181],[13.193,-54.181],[11.279,-43.103],[3.928,-43.103],[2.719,-36.255],[10.071,-36.255],[5.841,-11.984]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"t","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"t","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"h","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":52.5,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-5.237,0],[0.806,-4.733],[0,0],[-8.258,0],[-1.913,0.604],[0,0],[1.813,0],[-0.604,3.223],[0,0],[7.553,0],[4.431,-3.625],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[4.23,-3.827],[4.733,0],[0,0],[-1.108,6.244],[2.618,0],[0,0],[-1.41,0.504],[-2.82,0],[0,0],[1.611,-9.164],[-6.345,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[2.014,0],[10.675,0],[15.811,-29.004],[31.119,-37.262],[36.053,-29.105],[32.831,-10.776],[41.693,1.007],[48.642,-0.101],[49.85,-6.747],[44.614,-5.64],[41.29,-10.272],[44.614,-29.608],[33.939,-44.211],[17.12,-36.658],[23.264,-71.201],[6.949,-71.201],[5.74,-64.352],[13.394,-64.352]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"h","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"h","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"w","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":69.6,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[-3.424,6.647],[0,0],[0,0],[0,8.359],[5.64,0],[2.618,-2.014],[0,0],[-2.014,0],[0,-1.712],[8.258,-9.869],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[5.136,-6.848],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[5.539,-6.848],[0,0],[0,0],[11.481,-12.991],[0,-4.431],[-4.23,0],[0,0],[2.216,-1.41],[1.913,0],[0,5.338],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-2.216,6.647],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[15.71,0],[22.961,0],[36.859,-21.149],[41.492,0],[48.541,0],[68.481,-35.852],[60.526,-44.11],[49.548,-39.88],[51.865,-34.744],[58.209,-37.061],[60.727,-34.644],[46.829,-8.459],[40.082,-43.103],[27.493,-43.103],[26.285,-36.356],[33.334,-36.356],[34.241,-31.622],[21.249,-8.862],[14.703,-43.103],[2.316,-43.103],[1.108,-36.356],[7.956,-36.356]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"w","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"w","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"i","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":26.2,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-8.258,0],[-1.913,0.604],[0,0],[1.913,0],[-0.504,3.223],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[2.518,0],[0,0],[-1.41,0.504],[-2.719,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-1.108,6.345]],"v":[[14.804,1.007],[21.753,-0.101],[22.861,-6.747],[17.624,-5.64],[14.301,-10.272],[20.142,-43.103],[3.928,-43.103],[2.719,-36.154],[10.272,-36.154],[5.841,-10.776]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"i","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ind":1,"ty":"sh","ix":2,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[-3.223,0],[0,3.323],[3.323,0],[0,-3.323]],"o":[[3.323,0],[0,-3.323],[-3.223,0],[0,3.323]],"v":[[17.523,-51.965],[23.666,-58.008],[17.523,-64.05],[11.481,-58.008]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"i","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"i","np":5,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"},{"ch":"r","size":311,"style":"Medium Italic","w":41.2,"data":{"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[-4.834,0],[0,-1.611],[0.403,-1.208],[0,0],[0,2.417],[4.129,0],[3.928,-4.431],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[2.618,-2.82],[1.913,0],[0,1.309],[0,0],[0.806,-2.115],[0,-5.438],[-6.143,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[4.33,0],[12.991,0],[17.926,-28.098],[30.917,-36.758],[33.536,-34.14],[32.73,-30.011],[40.485,-29.507],[41.895,-36.658],[34.442,-44.211],[18.933,-35.349],[20.343,-43.103],[4.633,-43.103],[3.323,-36.154],[10.776,-36.154]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"r","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false}],"nm":"r","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}]},"fFamily":"Klinic Slab"}]}
```

Is it possible to do that with **some changes** in this file? I changed the text "healthwire" inside that file. But that action is not working and my new text is not showing in my WordPress site.